# Python Array size is doubled after saving in binary format

Tags: python, numpy

I have data stored in an array of size (4320,2160), reshaped from a list of length 4320*2160. When I save the file in binary format using numpy's tofile method, and then open the file I noticed that the array is double in length. How do I get the original values of the array? I'm assuming it has something to do with endianness, but i'm unfamiliar with dealing with it.

```
cdom=np.reshape(cdom, (4320,2160), order='F') # array of float values
len(cdom) # 4320*2160
cdom.tofile(filename)

arr = np.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.float32)
len(arr) # double the size of cdom: 2*4320*2160
```

Comment: What's mycdom? The result of the reshape?

Comment: @NathanBartley yes it is the result of the reshape. I should have been specific about that.

Comment: I suspect `cdom` has type `np.float64`, and you are reading the binary file as `np.float32`, so the length is doubled (and the values are effectively garbage).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're right! Thank you! changing the dtype to float64 fixed the problem.

Comment: OK, I'll make my comment an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cdom` has type `np.float64`, and you are reading the binary file as `np.float32`, so the length is doubled (and the values are effectively garbage).